# Showing home page but at the title it shows PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: php, wordpress, html

1. I have developed a wordpress theme. There are 2 pages HOME and ABOUT US. For home page I use index.php and for about us page I used page.php template. But when I click on home page it shows the title "page not found".
2. And I create a page named HOME then it is showing page contents which I posted in Home page but I need to show contents of index.php. (for example in index.php I have a slider. and I have created a page named "Home". When I click on home tab it is showing the contents that I posted on home page, NO SLIDER IS SHOWING)

Here is the site [admission247.com](http://admission247.com)

my page.php code

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="page_content">
<?php // echo '<br/><br/>'; ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the code.

Here is a snippet of code I use for my header.

```
<title><?php
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title("&laquo;", true, "right");

    bloginfo("name");

    $site_description = get_bloginfo("description", "display");

    if($site_description && (is_home() || is_front_page()))
        echo " &laquo; $site_description";

    if($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2)
    echo " &laquo; " . sprintf(__("Page %s", "h18"), max($paged, $page));
?></title>
```

If you can, post as much code as you can. It will help others understand your problem more.

Answer (score 0):

YOUR_try this

**functions.php**

```
    function site_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'YOUR_SITE' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'site_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

**header.php**

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```